# Applying some filter on my accelerometer data - Windows phone 8, C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, filter, accelerometer

I'm placing data from the accelerometer X into a spaceship so that when you tilt the phone left and right, it rolls left and right (slightly).

I have made a ratio because I want my spaceship to only rotate half way if the phone is tilted to -1 or 1 (full tilt).

```
// accelerometer = Accelerometer::GetDefault();
// player->maxTitle = 0.5 (half of full accelerometer tilt)
double accelX = accelerometer->GetX();
player->currentRotation = ( accelX * player->maxTilt );
```

Originally this worked really jolty and poorly, so I had a play with the interval settings, vast improvement but still junk... it's rather sensitive now.

```
accelerometer = Accelerometer::GetDefault();
int reportInterval = 16;
if( accelerometer->MinimumReportInterval > reportInterval )
{
    accelerometer->ReportInterval = reportInterval;
}
```

So I am assuming that I need to do some kind of low filter thing, wiener filter is it? to **smooth out** the value... can I have some hints and tips on doing such an operation?

I've tried a few formulas but am having difficulties getting them to work... http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,10716.0.html

Comment: If you want a kind of delayed reaction to the tilting (more realistic) then use the accelerometer to determine the max tilt and have a max accelleration which the ship will use to roll to the max tilt in its own time. Gets rid of the sensitivity and smooths the whole thing out. If you want to get tricky you can have a variable acelleration too.

Comment: I kinda would like my game mechanic to be that the ship rotates in direct correlation to the phones tilt, so it feels more.. attached. I have already tried increasing a number, it just didn't feel right. Thanks though

Comment: If thats the case, Instead though you could have an "align time" where your code calculates how fast the ship will need to tilt to align within some time frame (try 10 frames, ~166ms if you have delta_t) to the new tilt of the phone. It would basically be `accelleration = (new_angle-current_angle)/frames` keep rotating until the new tilt is hit and stop.

Answer (score 0):

The discrete equivalent of a low-pass filter is to limit the difference between multiple readings. This difference should not be too large, else you get the jerky behavior. So, if it  is, ignore the accelerometer value, and substitute the previous value plus the maximum allowed   difference.

Assume readings 1 6 9 and a maximum change of 4, you'd substitute the 6 with a 5. The differences have now become 4 4 instead of 5 3, which indeed is smoother. There are even smoother filters (using more state), but this should already help.

Comment: Absolutely awesome, and makes sense... I'll have a stab at it when I get home.